# Add a Column to an existing CSV file with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, import

I'm trying to add a new column header and values to an existing csv file with python. Every thing I've looked up appends the header to the last row of the last column.  This is what I want my results to be essentially.

`Header   Header2   Header3  NewHeader
 Value    Value2    Value3   NewValue`

What I'm currently getting is this:

```
Header   Header2   Header3
Value    Value2    Value3**NewHeader
NewValue`
```

This is my code:

```
import csv
  with open('filename.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
  fieldnames = ['pageviewid']
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

  writer.writeheader()
  writer.writerow({'pageviewid': 'Baked'})
  writer.writerow({'pageviewid': 'Lovely'})
  writer.writerow({'pageviewid': 'Wonderful'})
```

Comment: Aren't at least some of the lines after the 'with' statement indented?

Comment: to add column you have to read all csv to memory, add column in memory, and save all file again. `'a'` means `append` but it can only append at the end of file.

Answer (score 4):

If using pandas is an option:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
new_column = pd.DataFrame({'new_header': ['new_value_1', 'new_value_2', 'new_value_3']})
df = df.merge(new_column, left_index = True, right_index = True)
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Using this method, a new column is added to the left of my data. The rest of the code works, do you know how I could get rid of this column? It starts from 0 to the end of my list so its probably enumerating the index of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to rewrite to an output file

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'))
headers = reader.next()
headers.append("Brand New Awesome Header")
writer.writerow(headers)
for row in reader:
    row.append(new data for my new header)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You don't need to read a text file in binary mode.  Is there another reason for the 'rb' mode?  Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @Chris Kenyon I'd assume you meant `writer.writerow` rather than `writer.write`.